# HTTP digest authentication for AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, http, digest-authentication

Hey SO, so I've got an API I'm making calls to in a browser application. Said API lives on a server that requires whitelisting and HTTP Digest Authentication.

To meet the whitelisting requirement, I'm running all API calls through a proxy, which is whitelisted. The calls are originating from an iFrame, currently populated by an `index.html` file.

What I need to know is how I can authenticate via HTTP Digest in the background. Most of the resources I can find online seem to involve the **original** HTTP Digest Authentication setup, but what I'm looking to do is automate login.

Despite the non-secretive subject matter, it is somehow critical that I keep the digest parameters obfuscated from users. Perhaps I could change the served file to `index.php` and then somehow set the magic headers? Even then, if the calls made via XHR, would the index.php headers authenticate the separate request?

Overall, I'm just lost, and the API developers in question are not exactly responsive, so thought I'd turn here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in the end, this was not possible. I had to switch to building a thin back-end to route requests through.